# Ubuntu Crontab error

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, cron, syntax, crontab

I want to list files at 12h01.  How can I set my crontab to do this?

```
pedro@Pedro-PC:~/PL/trab4$ crontab -l
# 01 12 * * * ls -l
```

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: Redirect your output in the script to a known file location

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the

```
ls -l
```

command into a small bash script .... name the file `listfiles` for an example

The put `listfiles`  in somewhere like `/usr/bin`

make listfiles executable with

```
sudo chmod +x listfiles
```

then change your crontab to

```
01 12 * * * /usr/bin/listfiles
```

Comment: Is all worthless, if the output is on the virtual console and no screen attached, nor the output of ls -l redirected to somewhere...

Answer (score 1):

You can also (which I prefer for smaller commands) do what you did at first, but with the full path to the ls binary. Crontab runs with a smaller $PATH than you do, which is why we give the full path to ls.

ie:

```
01 12 * * * /bin/ls /home/user/
```

You can get the path to your binary with

```
which ls
```

Comment: not working, don't happend nothing

Comment: What happens when you try * * * * * /bin/ls /
?
Assuming of course, that your ls is located at /bin/ls ..

Comment: Good hint to use full pathes for programms run by root, but still the output of ls will never be seen, nor be saved anywhere...

Answer (score 1):

As I stated in your other question, errors and warnings from `cron` and `at` can be viewed in your local mail.

And your cronjob is wrong, it should be something like:

```
01 12 * * * ls -l [somedir] > [some file with results]
```

[somedir] is the directory you are trying to list.

[some file with results] is a path to the file that will store your result.